# Can I transplant plumeria in late September? (north hemisphere)

Tags: transplanting, overwintering

I've got two potted plumeria since last spring, and they thrived so much that their pots have become too small now. I'm wondering if late September is a good period for replanting in bigger containers. I read that it's not adviced replanting plumeria while they're dormant (wintertime). So, I'm not sure whether I can do it now that summer is almost gone. It's officially gone, but not for the weather here. I live in zone 10a as per USDA hardiness classification, and we expect min temperatures of 17-18C (62-64F) for two weeks at least.

[image]

Comment: I can't think of a reason to not transplant when dormant.  When I first saw plumeria ,i t was at the Houston garden club. They looked like short curved broomsticks ( very dormant ). I was assured they would grow and they did.

Comment: So you would rather wait till winter to transplant them?

Comment: I think the only risk is breaking up the root ball and exposing roots regardless of season.

Comment: I'll try it this afternoon with care. Thanks for the advice!